# Why does my NodeJS lambda function execute multiple times upon a single invocation?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a NodeJS script hosted as a AWS lambda function. The script basically queries data from MySQL database.

In summary it has a loop wherein for each iteration a query operation is executed. This is awaited and then logged and then it moves to the next iteration.

This works fine when I execute the function locally but when I invoke it in the lambda using the serverless framework, the same async query fires multiple times as checked in the logs.
For a single invocation there are multiple log streams in AWS cloudwatch which concludes that the function is running on multiple instances.

I have tried to configure the retry attempts for failure option to 0 (from default 2) but it doesn't help. Even catching all the async requests and having error free logs, it still executes multiple times due to which it runs for the entire maximum duration of 15minutes.

Can someone help me on this issue.

Following is the code snippet of the function body

```js
const runDailyAggregation = async() => {
  const time = moment();
  const date = moment(time).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
  const unixFromTime = moment(time).startOf('day').unix()
  const unixToTime = moment(time).endOf('day').unix();
  let plantList = await getPlantList();
  const aggregateParameterConfig = await getAggregateParamterConfig()

  for (let plantId of plantList) {
    const deviceList = Object.keys(aggregateParameterConfig)
    for (let device of deviceList) {
      const deviceParameters = aggregateParameterConfig[device]
      const promises = Object.entries(deviceParameters).map(async([parameter, cumulativeType]) => {
        let res;
        try {
          res = await executeQuery({
            plantId,
            device,
            parameter,
            unixFromTime,
            unixToTime,
            cumulativeType,
          })
        } catch (e) {
          return `ERROR RETRIEVING | ${plantId} | ${device} | ${parameter} | ${e.message} | ${e.code}`
        }

        if (!res || !res.length)
          return `NO DATA | ${plantId} | ${device} | ${parameter}`;

        const arrayToInsert = res.map(({
          device_id: deviceId,
          ...obj
        }) => {
          return ({
            date,
            plantId,
            device,
            deviceId,
            parameter,
            value: JSON.stringify(obj)
          })
        })
        try {
          await insertAggregateData(arrayToInsert)
        } catch (e) {
          return `ERROR INSERTING | ${plantId} | ${device} | ${parameter} | ${e.message} | ${e.code}`
        }
        return `SUCCESSFULLY INSERTED DATA | ${plantId} | ${device} | ${parameter}`
      })
      const res = await Promise.all(promises)
      console.log(`PLANT - ${plantId} DEVICE - ${device}`, JSON.stringify(res, null, 2))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the trigger of the lambda when using the serverless framework?

Comment: Check your logs for errors. My guess is that one of your promises returns Promise.reject. It causes lambda to crash and retry.

Comment: @ShahadIshraq it is trigger with the from terminal with the command `sls invoke -f <function-name>`

Comment: @karjan I have check the logs. There are few operation timeout errors which I guess is related to the sql query , but all these are caught in the catch block and logged. Apart from these there are no errors.

Comment: Can you share the logs?

Comment: My guess is, the lambda is long running and the `sls invoke` call times out before the lambda can finish. So it retries internally and creates second invocation .

Comment: Check your Lambda error count, also set your re-try limit to 0 and see if it still gets called multiple times?

Comment: @ShahadIshraq I think you were right about that. When I ran it directly from aws console, it ran as expected (just one execution). Thank You. It was really bugging me.